How can directories in a macOS APFS root directory be in other filesystems without being links or mountpoints?
I found a very unusual behaviour about the root file system / on modern macOS which are now all using
the Apple propriatary file system APFS.
With a basic set of filesystems defined through the
Big Sur installation as follows:
### 18:04       noether:/       # mount | grep disk1
/dev/disk1s5s1 on / (apfs, sealed, local, read-only, journaled)
/dev/disk1s4 on /System/Volumes/VM (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /System/Volumes/Preboot (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s6 on /System/Volumes/Update (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s1 on /System/Volumes/Data (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s5 on /Volumes/noether 1 250 Go 1 (apfs, sealed, local, journaled, nobrowse)
### 18:04       noether:/       #

I discovered that at the base of this file system, i.e. in / directly there are files which belongs to the / FS when some other belongs to the /System/Volumes/Data FS:
### 18:14       noether:/       # ffs
--------------------------------------------
file                    volume                          
--------------------------------------------
.file                   /                               
.vol                    /                               
Applications            /System/Volumes/Data            
Library                 /System/Volumes/Data            
System                  /                               
Users                   /System/Volumes/Data            
Volumes                 /System/Volumes/Data            
bin                     /                               
cores                   /System/Volumes/Data            
dev                     /dev                            
etc                     /System/Volumes/Data            
home                                                    
opt                     /System/Volumes/Data            
private                 /System/Volumes/Data            
sbin                    /                               
tmp                     /System/Volumes/Data            
usr                     /                               
var                     /System/Volumes/Data            
### 18:14       noether:/       # 

( where ffs is a small shell script¹ printing the FS a file belongs to in the working directory ).
How is this possible when there is only one FS which can be mounted on / and some of these files are symbolic links toward /System/Volumes/Data ( like home ) but some others are plain directories ( like opt and private ):
### 18:20       noether:/       # ls -alt
total 18
drwxr-xr-x  19 root  wheel   608 Aug  3 18:50 Volumes
drwxrwxr-x  32 root  admin  1024 Aug  3 12:33 Applications
drwxr-xr-x  15 root  admin   480 Jul 19 15:54 Users
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    25 Jul 13 23:22 home -> /System/Volumes/Data/home
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  8886 Jul 13 23:22 dev
drwxr-xr-x  15 root  wheel   480 Mar 26 21:47 opt
drwxr-xr-x  71 root  wheel  2272 Jan 20  2024 Library
drwxr-xr-x  20 root  wheel   640 Jan  1  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 root  wheel   640 Jan  1  2020 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    36 Jan  1  2020 .VolumeIcon.icns -> System/Volumes/Data/.VolumeIcon.icns
----------   1 root  admin     0 Jan  1  2020 .file
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    64 Jan  1  2020 .vol
drwxr-xr-x@  9 root  wheel   288 Jan  1  2020 System
drwxr-xr-x@ 38 root  wheel  1216 Jan  1  2020 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    64 Jan  1  2020 cores
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11 Jan  1  2020 etc -> private/etc
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel   192 Jan  1  2020 private
drwxr-xr-x@ 65 root  wheel  2080 Jan  1  2020 sbin
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11 Jan  1  2020 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 root  wheel   352 Jan  1  2020 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11 Jan  1  2020 var -> private/var
### 18:20       noether:/

I know that this cannot work on any Unix.
This can only be related to APFS special features.
I am digging inside the Apple documentation about this
anomaly.

¹)    ffs source:
#!/bin/sh
printf "--------------------------------------------\n%-20s\t%-32s\n--------------------------------------------\n" "file" "volume" 
for _file in .* * ; do
if [ -e ${_file} ] ; then
        _volume=`df ${_file} | awk '/dev/ { print $NF}'`
        printf "%-20s\t%-32s\n" "${_file}" "${_volume}"
fi
done


An APFS filesystem can consist of multiple volumes, each of which has its own mount point. Each volume appears as a separate block device, but they all use the same disk space. A macOS installation has a root volume, a Data volume and a few others that contain non-user-serviceable files. The root volume is read-only except when doing maintenance (such as jailbreaking, restoring backups or upgrading the base OS).
Several directories of the root filesystem need to be modifiable in day-to-day use. All of these directories are in the Data volume. In order to make this as transparent as possible, those directories appear as actual directories: they are seen as directories by stat(2) and ls(1), and pwd -P does not expand them further. However, under the hood, they are not directories, but firmlinks, which are intermediate between hard links and symbolic links. They are directional, unlike hard links. But they are pointers to a specific entry in the same filesystem rather than to a named path, unlike symbolic links. Firmlinks are new in macOS 10.15 Catalina.
See How to find firmlinks. I can't find a utility that reveals whether a given directory is actually a firmlink. You can see the list of firmlinks from the root volume to the Data volume that are supposed to be present on your system in /usr/share/firmlinks.

This volume grouping with the appearance of a uniq name space is only applied to a very special set: the / and the /System/Volumes/Data. This is implemented with the APFS concept of "Volume Group" in ΑppIe wording, and the file, outside of the FS internal , you named: /usr/share/firmlinks
